# divisibility of $a^m+a-1$ by $a^n+a^2-1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

Find all integers $m,n\geq 3$ such as the polynomial $a^m+a-1$ is divisible by $a^n+a^2-1$.

---

It is clear that $m=n+k$ for some integer $k\geq 0$, we find that $\left(a^n+a^2-1\right)|\left(a^{k+1}+a^{k}-1\right)$.
but I can't go further.

Comment: You have a mismatch between your title and question content.  Which polynomial is dividing which?

Comment: @abiessu sorry, I took care of it.

Comment: It is Problem 3 from IMO'2002.  Among the shortlisted problems, it shows up as the Problem N6: https://anhngq.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/imo-2002-shortlist.pdf.